# traversing js object properties adds quotes to strings in jade view

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using npm module [traverse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/traverse) to filter data coming from mongodb / mongoose.

I might get this data:

```
[ { rating: 5,
    title: { da: 'Web udvikling', en: 'Web Development' } },
  { rating: 5, title: { da: 'Node.js', en: 'Node.js' } } ]
```

'da' and 'en' indicates languages. I use [traverse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/traverse) to filter mongoose data after current language like this:

```
var filtered = filterLanguage(lang, results);
// filter json obj by language
var filterLanguage = function(language, obj) {
    return traverse(obj).map(function (item) {
        if (this.key === language) {
            this.parent.update(item);
        }
    });
};
```

I then show this in my template:

```
res.render('index', {
    skills: filtered.skills
});
```

Finally I display it in the jade view:

```
ul.list-group
    each skill, i in skills
        if i < 5
            li.list-group-item.sidebar-list-item= skill.title
```

Unfortunately it's displayed with quotes:

```
<ul>
    <li>'Web Development'</li>
    <li>'Node.js'</li>
</ul>
```

These quotes are not there in the unfiltered data (`results.skill.title.da`). So traverse is adding them. I used the module with 'plain' json and it's working perfectly.

The mongoose data seems plain and simple but of course there are a lot of properties on the prototype. Also traverse stalls if I don't omit '_id' (type bson/objectid) property from result set.

So traverse seems to have problems with mongoose data... Why is this? And how can I fix it?

---

-- **EDIT** --

I found a solution:

Before filtering I do this: 

`var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
var filtered = filterLanguage(lang, json);`

This removes the quotes, but I'm not sure exactly what it does. Somehow converting the mongoose result to JSON? An explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fields in Mongoose documents are getters/setters, which seem to confuse either `traverse` or Jade/Pug.

The shortest method I found that seems to fix all of your issues is pretty ugly:

```
var filtered = filterLanguage(lang, results.map(r => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r))));
```

A more elaborate version:

```
var filtered = filterLanguage(lang, results.map(r => {
  let j = r.toJSON()
  j._id = j._id.toString()
  return j;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful to see what is the body of `filterLanguage` exactly or understand why it's called twice but as it stands, I don't think you need to use the `traverse` package at all.

A function such as below should do the trick and I even expanded it to work if the data is more tree-like and not as flat as represented in your example.

```
const reduceByLang = (data, lang) => {
  // Look for a `lang` key in obj or
  // if not found but still an object, recurse
  const reduceByLangObj = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      if (obj[key] === null) {
        return;
      }
      if (obj[key][lang]) {
        obj[key] = obj[key][lang]; // replace with desired lang
      } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        reduceByLangObj(obj[key]); // recurse
      }
    });
    return obj;
  };

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.map(reduceByLangObj);
  } else {
    return reduceByLangObj(data);
  }
};
```

See example in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/zayuqiqifi/edit?js,console).

Also, if possible at all and if you do this type of selecting very often, I would look into saving the data in a different structure:

`{ ratings: x, locales: { en: { title: 'Y' }, { da: { title: 'Z' } } } }`

maybe, so that you can pick the selected language easily either in the query itself and/or in the controller.

EDIT: Checking for null.

Comment: I included filterLanguage() method body in the question. It should not be called twice, that was a typo. Only once - updated question to that also.

Comment: Your solution reduceByLang gives me this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'da' of undefined"

Comment: That's interesting, I haven't been able to reproduce that exact error although  I tried adding in arrays, a function etc. in the data array. The only thing that broke was if the property is `null` but it wasn't the same error. Do you mind sharing more about the structure of the full data?